# how can i get data from another sheet column and extract only number

Tags: excel

Column C in Sheet 4 get Column M in Sheet 1
using this

```
=IF(Sheet1!M4<>"",Sheet1!M4,"")
```

Now I'm trying to extract only number from Column C in Sheet 4

Here in another tab I successfully extract only number,

using this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$25),1))*
```

But how can I combine this formula together with my previous formula?

So in Column C in Sheet 4, I can both get Column M in Sheet 1 and extract only number Column C in Sheet 4.

Column M in Sheet 1

```
fg+_2//3
cc+_2++++3
sd()*))41nnn
```

Column C in Sheet 4

```
23
23
41
```

Thank you

Comment: Give some examples of what you have and what you expect the final result to be.

Comment: @ PGCodeRider please take a look

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Still not that clear. Screen shots or something else. Good luck.

Comment: Column C in Sheet 4 get data from Column M in Sheet 1. In Column C in Sheet 4 only number are extracted